# Show Original adaptive card in teams after submit

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I have implemented a requirement where i need to post a adaptive card from Power automate to a user through Flow bot and get response to log it.
But after clicking on "Submit" original adaptive card is lost and response card is getting displayed.
Is there any way by which we can retain the original card after response.

**Original card:**

[image]

**Card after submitting comments:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is by design and it is not possible to retain the original card after response. In the attached screenshot you can see there is no option to retain the original card in the flow.
[image]

Comment: @mehana - Thanks so much for response, in one the internet reference i found one option so do you have any idea if it has been removed from preview. Ref: https://ashiqf.com/2020/02/09/collect-response-from-a-user-with-adaptive-card-in-teams-using-power-automate/
it have option "Should update card"

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal- This feature was in preview before and its deprecated now.